# Working of push in react while using redux to update the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The following code is the code for my reducer where i am calling these function in my container

```
const intialState = {
  counter: 0,
  results: []
};

const reducer = (state = intialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter + 1
      };

    case "STORE_RESULT": {
      return {
        ...state,
        results: state.results.push(state.counter)
      };
    }
  }
  return state;
};

export default reducer;
```

I am getting following error

```
TypeError: state.results.push is not a function
reducer
```

1) I am using redux reducer in my project

2) I am updating the state by passing the type from my dispatch in my container

3) I am trying to update the array by pushing(i know it returns the length ) but i want to know why it is not working

4) Following code i tryed in javascript everything worked fine

```
var a = {
b:[]
}
a.b.push(11)
//output
1
```

Comment: Push mutates, you should not mutate. Also push doesn't return anything so I think you meant to use concat

Comment: I was just about to say the above: try `results: state.results.concat([state.counter])` and let us know if it works.

Comment: concat perfectly workes but i want to know why push failed

Comment: push doesn't return a new array. You're storing an `int` in `results`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push` returns the new `length` of the mutated `array`. Use `concat` instead which returns a new array

```
results : state.results.concat(item)
```

Let's assume the following code

```
results : state.results.push('foo')
```

Assuming that  `results` has a `length` of `5`, the above code will assert to

```
results : 5
```

Next time you try to `push` `results` this is what will look like to your compiler

```
5.push('foo')
```

Comment: ok 
i am thinking my result is expecting an array but i am giving number so it is throwing the error (concat worked but thinking why push failed)  correct me if was wrong

Comment: what do error means state.results.push is not a function

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Didnt know that push returns a length. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

[the return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Return_value) of `.push` is

> The new length property of the object upon which the method was called.

to add the value to `stae.results` use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) or [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) :

```
case "STORE_RESULT": {
  return {
    ...state,
    results: [...state.results, state.counter]
  };
}
```

Comment: ok 
i am thinking my result is expecting an array but i am giving number so it is throwing the error (concat worked but thinking why push failed)  correct me if was wrong
What do error means

Answer (score 1):

you should add default case in reducer switch.

and use the `[...state.results, state.counter]` instead of `state.results.push(state.counter)`.

***like this***

```
const intialState = {
  counter: 0,
  results: []
};

const reducer = (state = intialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter + 1
      };

    case "STORE_RESULT": {
      return {
        ...state,
        results: [...state.results, state.counter] // here
      };
    default:
      return state; // here
    }
  }
};

export default reducer;
```